# Get URL for individual figure from Bokeh Server

Tags: bokeh

I have a Bokeh server application where each page has a few different figures.

Is there a way to get a separate URL for each plot individually?  I'm happy to specify id's for my bokeh figures if that helps.

Comment: Could you tell us, what you intend to do? You could set up different URL handlers and prepare one document/Application per figure.

Comment: Yeah, that's my backup plan.  It would be nice to have access to them automatically without flooding my TOC with many tiny plots.  I plan to put all of my plots into JupyterLab panes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Bokeh `0.13.0`, no, there is not.

Comment: Thanks @bigreddot !